# redisとphp間のセッション数削減

Tags: php, redis

redisをphpから使っています。

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

のようにredisにセッションを行うとき、phpプログラムが読み出される度にセッションは多くなっていきます。つまりアクセスが多いサイトでこのphpプログラムを実行する形ではセッション数がシステムキャパを超える可能性があります。

Redisとphpのセッションを張ったままで、新たに来たリクエストについては前に張ったセッションで行うという対応も聞いたことがあります。

実際どのような実装になるのでしょうか？もしくは別の方法もご存知であればご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

見当違いでしたらすみませんが、もし Laravel を使用されている場合は、Redis ファサードを利用してはいかがでしょうか？

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
```

としておき、必要箇所で、例えば以下のように使用できるかと思います。

```
//キーが key の値を取得する
$value = Redis::get('key');
//有効期限 10 秒でキー key に値 value を設定する
Redis::setex('key', 10, 'value);
```